# Trigonometry identities sum and substraction of cosine

Tags: trigonometry

Someone can help me showing this identity?

$\frac{cos(a-b)}{cos(a+b)}=\frac{1+tan(a)tan(b)}{1-tan(a)tan(b)}$

Comment: Start by using the angle-sum (difference) formulas for $\cos$.

Comment: Please let us know your progress so far. Hint: Expand both Nr and Dr

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668619/proving-a-trig-identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the angle sum formula for $\cos$:

$$\frac{\cos(a-b)}{\cos(a+b)}= \frac{\cos a \cos b + \sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}$$

Hint: Now all you need to do is to divide the numerator and denominator by $(\cos a\cos b)...$

Answer (score 3):

We start with $\frac{1+tan(a)tan(b)}{1-tan(a)tan(b)}$:

$\frac{1+tan(a)tan(b)}{1-tan(a)tan(b)}=\frac{1+\frac{sin (a)sin (b)}{cos (a)cos (b)}}{1-\frac{sin (a)sin (b)}{cos (a)cos (b)}}=\frac{\frac{cos (a)cos (b)+sin (a)sin (b)}{cos (a)cos (b)}}{\frac{cos (a)cos (b)-sin (a)sin (b)}{cos (a)cos (b)}}=\frac{cos (a)cos (b)+sin (a)sin (b)}{cos (a)cos (b)-sin (a)sin (b)}=\frac{cos(a-b)}{cos(a+b)}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos(a-b)}{\cos(a+b)}&=\frac{\cos a\cos b+ \sin a\sin b}{\cos a\cos b- \sin a\sin b}\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\cos a\cos b+ \sin a\sin b}{\cos a\cos b}}{\displaystyle\frac{\cos a\cos b- \sin a\sin b}{\cos a\cos b}}\\
&=\; ?
\end{align*}